Kafka - Store the not-consumed messages before being discarded
As per the Kafka documentation here.

The Kafka cluster retains all published messages—whether or not they have been consumed—for a configurable period of time. For example if the log retention is set to two days, then for the two days after a message is published it is available for consumption, after which it will be discarded to free up space.

Is there any way to store (like in a db) the not-consumed messages before being discarded after the retention period by Kafka?

Kafka deletes the log if either log.retention.hours or log.retention.bytes is exceeded. In your case if you want to store those unconsumed messages which are going to be deleted,
First find till where previous consumers have consumed data using similar  command as below,
/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group 1
Now try to store unconsumed messages in file by starting the kafka-console-consumer by providing proper offset from where you want to consume unconsumed messages.
/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server  --topic  --partition 1 --offset 1060  > file.out
